# Пунктуация. Словосочетание "случайным образом"

Tags: пунктуация

Выделяется ли запятыми словосочетание "случайным образом"?

Например:
*Так в одной из соцсетей **(,) случайным образом(,)** наткнулась на странноватого парня.*

Answer (score 1):

В этом предложении "случайным образом" является обстоятельством и не обособляется.

Вообще говоря, обстоятельства, даже одиночные, иногда обособляются, но "случайным образом" практически никогда не выделяется запятыми.  Но интересно то, что при распространении  обстоятельственный оборот уже может обособляться, например: "иногда случайным образом" или "часто случайным образом." Тогда  он будет считаться попутным замечанием, такие примеры мне встречались в тексте.

И еще мне кажется, что обособление возможно (но не обязательно) в исходном предложении, если его немного изменить: "Так в одной из соц. сетей наткнулась, случайным образом, на странноватого парня. Здесь автор может выбрать, какое значение (основное или попутное) имеет это словосочетание. (Перестановка сделана для удобства обособления).

Answer (score 0):

Нет, это не вводное слово, а член предложения – обстоятельство образа действия. Наткнулась (как? каким образом?) случайным образом. Напомню,что вводные слова членами предложения не бывают.